# Найти индексы массива, которые в сумме дают заданное число Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list

Учитывая массив целых чисел nums и целое число target, верните индексы двух чисел так, чтобы их сумма равнялась target.

Вы можете предположить, что каждый вход будет иметь ровно одно решение, и вы не можете использовать один и тот же элемент дважды.
Проблема в том, что в массиве с одинаковыми числами не возвращает результат. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

```
def sum_of_two(nums: list, target: int) -> list:
    step = 0
    for x in nums:
        for y in nums:
            if x + y == target and nums.index(x) != nums.index(y):
                print([nums.index(x), nums.index(y)])
                step = 1
                break
        if step == 1:
            break
    return nums.index(x), nums.index(y)
sum_of_two([3, 3], 6)
```

Comment: метод `index` возвращает **первое** вхождение элемента в список

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=nums+target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `.index()` возвращает индекс первого совпадения, поэтому при равных числах будет возвращать один и тот же индекс. Перебирайте индексы вместо этого.

```
def sum_of_two(nums: list, target: int) -> list:
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
            if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                return [i, j]


print(sum_of_two([3, 2, 1, 8, 3], 6))
```

```
[0, 4]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое